# Clear structure in c#

Tags: c#

Say I have a structure with several members eg.

```
private struct MyStats
{
    public int packsGood, packsBad, packsTotal;
    public bool haveAcceptedStart;
    // ...and a bunch of other parameters
}
```

If I have a member variable of type MyStats, how do I use it for a while and then quickly clear it? In Delphi or C++ I might have used the following code:

```
memset(&m_stats, 0, sizeof(MyStats));       // C++
ZeroMemory(@m_stats, SizeOf(MyStats));      // Delphi
```

but that doesn't appear possible in C#. Surely I don't have to rattle through all members each time or PInvoke an API call?

Comment: Why not just assign an empty / new instance of the structure to the member variable?

Comment: In C# objects don't need to be "cleared", the garbage collector will free memory that is occupied by objects that are no longer in use by the program as soon as the system needs it. So you just need to make sure that the object is not needed anymore.

Comment: m_stats = new MyStats();

Comment: You misunderstand both what a C# struct is and what happens in C++. A `struct` has **value** semantics, meaning it isn't supposed to change like this. The code you wrote is considered very, *very*, **very**  bad form in **C++** as you are mixing direct memory manipulation with functions like `new` and `delete`. If you want to use a specific memory area in C++ you should use placement new, **NOT** wipe the structure. Finally, the cost of wiping is typically greater than creating a new instance.

Comment: @HansPassant: but that creates a new object with the same size, so it does not really "clear it". It just replaces it with a different one.

Comment: It is not an object, it is a structure.  The *new* syntax is just syntax sugar in C#, it doesn't actually allocate anything from the heap.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/340786b7-730f-4f06-980f-84194c6e9533/how-do-you-clear-a-struct-empty-a-struct-?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @HansPassant: i'm not sure. If i got it right, this article calls that a myth: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/11/debunking-another-myth-about-value-types.aspx
_" The mythical part is right here: ...using the new operator on a value type allocates no additional memory. Rather, the memory already allocated for the value is used.

**That's not true**"_

Comment: "Allocating a temporary" are heavy words, they have very little to do with the code that the jitter generates.  Setting a processor register to zero is not heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory Management should generally not be one of your concerns in C#, as opposed to C or C++. There is the garbage collector to take care of memory clearing. As soon as all the references to your struct have disappeared, the garbage collector will reclaim the memory somewhere in the future. When exactly is irrelevant for a developer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are rare circumstances where you need to get a bit of determinism from the garbage collector with GC.Collect (eg. embedded systems with limited memory / CPU resources).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field in your class just to be used for a while an clearing it then your class isn't properly designed and does not comply with OOP principles.

If you are using that field just as an auxiliary value you should just replace it with a variable in every scope it is used; in this way you'll reduce the number of daunting side effects and since it's a value type it will be allocated on the stack and cleared as soon as the control flow leaves the current block (given you don't capture it in a lambda expression).